# How to find good observations for reinforcement learning?

Tags: sequence, reinforcement-learning

I am starting with my study of RL and was wondering how would one approach the observation features, which are not able to represent the state(hidden)?

Is there some systematic approach or some guidelines on how one would prefer the feature vector to look like? Discrete, dimension, Markov properties, embedding quality...?

I would like to process machine operation data streams and actually have a lot of direct measurements and many high-dim feature-vector (also stream).

Thank you very much for you input.